# Ternary operator in TypeScript does not work on JSX

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, jsx, operator-keyword

I have 2 variables that determine which components to render. personalInfo and cliente.

The problem I have is that when `personalInfo` equals `false`, the `CompleteInfo` component is not displayed (rendered). Instead, `HomeCliente` or `HomeProveedor` is rendered depending on the client variable.

```
<Route
  path="/home"
  render={() =>
    personalInfo ? (
      cliente ? (
        <HomeCliente />
      ) : (
        <HomeProveedor />
      )
    ) : (
      <Completarinfo setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain} />
    )
  }
></Route>
```

Apparently the ternary operator is walking backwards. What is the problem here?

```
return (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
        <Menu renderAgain={renderAgain} />
        <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
          <Route
            path="/home"
            render={() =>
              personalInfo ? (
                cliente ? (
                  <HomeCliente />
                ) : (
                  <HomeProveedor />
                )
              ) : (
                <Completarinfo setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain} />
              )
            }
          ></Route>
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonSplitPane>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using JSX (the HTML tags interspersed in JavaScript/TypeScript), and that the operator in question is the ternary operator, not the Elvis. I submitted an edit to your question to that effect. I don't work with JSX much myself, but I think you may need to wrap the `<HomeCliente>`, `<HomeProveedor>` and `<CompletarInfo>` tags in parentheses for them to work within the ternary operator.

Comment: Agreed on ternery, never heard about 'elvis' operator. Your code looks fine, which means that 1 of 2 things are true: Either: 1) you don't fully understand what the ternery operator is for. I suspect this because you used a different name... or 2) personalInfo does not have in it what you think it does.

Comment: Based on your description, I think you just need to replace `personalInfo` with `!personalInfo`, but I'm not 100% sure.